# Help with strong induction

Tags: coq, inductive-type, induction, natural-numbers

I have the following definition of divisibility by 3.

```ml
Inductive div3 : nat -> Prop :=
| div0 : div3 0
| divS : forall n : nat, div3_2 n -> div3 (S n)
with div3_2 : nat -> Prop :=
| div2 : div3_2 2
| div2S : forall n : nat, div3_1 n -> div3_2 (S n)
with div3_1 : nat -> Prop :=
| div1 : div3_1 1
| div1S : forall n : nat, div3 n -> div3_1 (S n).
```

How can I go about proving the following lemma?

```ml
Lemma practice : forall n : nat, div3 n -> exists m, n = 3 * m.
```

Comment: We're not a proof-completion service. Please moderate your questions because you will saturate the collective willingness to help by posting random questions in which you do not even indicate what you've tried and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As `div3` is defined using a mutual inductive definition with `div3_1` and `div3_2`.
The stronger statement you may try to prove is

```ml
Lemma practice : 
  (forall n : nat, div3 n -> exists m, n = 3 * m) /\
  (forall n : nat, div3_1 n -> exists m, n = 3 * m + 1) /\
  (forall n : nat, div3_2 n -> exists m, n = 3 * m + 2).
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to prove a slightly modified version of `practice` by a single  induction on `n`, using `inversion` tactics.

```
Lemma practice n : 
   (div3 n -> exists m, n = 3 * m) /\
   (div3_1 n -> exists m, n = S (3 * m)) /\
   (div3_2 n -> exists m, n = 2 + 3 * m ).
Proof. 
  induction n. 
  - repeat split; now exists 0. 
  -  destruct IHn as [H0 [H1 H2]]; repeat split.
     + inversion_clear 1.  
       destruct (H2 H3) as [x Hx]; exists (S x); subst; ring. 
     + inversion  1. 
        * subst n; exists 0; ring. 
        * subst n0; destruct (H0 H4) as [x Hx]; exists x; now subst. 
     + inversion 1.
       * subst n ; now exists 0. 
       * destruct (H1 H4) as [x Hx];  subst ; exists x; ring. 
Qed.
```

For a better understanding, you may replace the use of `inversion`  with diy "inversion lemmas" .

```
Lemma div3_inv n : div3 n -> n = 0 \/ exists p, n = S p /\ div3_2 p.
Proof. 
  destruct 1 as [|n Hn].
  - now left.   
  - right; exists n; auto. 
Qed. 

(* ... *)
```